# Set Routing Type Queue on Enhanced Eintein Bot

Tags: visual-workflow, omnichannel, einstein-chatbot, chatbot, bot

I'm trying to set routing type to an queue on Eintein bot, but it is not even leting me select the route type "queue". I don't know if this have anything to do, but I'm using the enhanced bot, cause in the standard version I could have done this easily. Also, it has an option that didn't had before: "Omnini-Channel Flow", how im showing in the following image.

[image]

[image]

I took a look in this flow and noticed that, in there, I can set the routing type to a queue, but I wish I could dynamically set the queue with an variable, because even tho I created a variable to use as input, in the bot, I just can't assign the content of the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with enhanced bot you can only use omni-channel flows.In my case i used 2 rules that set the omni-channel flow i want the bot to use based on the answer of the question. basicaly this 2 omnichannel flows are the same thing but changing the queue (i did not find a way to do this using variables within the flow)

[image: example]